# A wierd behavior when I have a link tag with a relative path in its href

Tags: php

I installed lampp recently in my linux machin, the sources files should be placed in /opt/lampp/htdocs directory which is annoying to work with... so what I did is creating a Symbolic link which point to that directory like that :

```
sudo ln -s /home/medBo/projects /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

Now I have my project in the following path : **/home/medBo/projects/ecommerce/** and everything work fine

In a view I have a link like this :

```
<a href="/test/hello">click here</a>
```

what I expect from that link is to be pointed to **localhost/projects/ecommerce/test/hello** but when I hover the mouse over it or I click it, it send me to **localhost/test/hello**

Isn't **localhost/projects/ecommerce/** considered as my site root ? what I can do about it ?

**UPDATE :**

Someone suggested in the comment to add `<base herf="http://localhost/projects/ecommerce">` in the head of the page, well the issue with this is when I go to this url

**localhost/projects/ecommerce/some-controller/some-action**

and inside that page there is a link to **/go-to-other-controller/other-action**

The destination becomes **localhost/projects/ecommerce/some-controller/some-action/go-to-other-controller/other-action**

Comment: Your server's document root and your site's web root are two different things.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol What do you mean by that ?

Comment: `/path/to/url` means `<protocol>://<site.i.was.at>/path/to/url` while `path/to/url` (no leading `/`) means `<protocol>://<site.i.was.at>/<path/I/was/at>/path/to/url`

Comment: You can also add an `<base herf="http://localhost/projects/ecommerce">` in the `<head>` part of the page to get it working. but all *relativ* pathes will use this e.g. js files, images ..

Comment: @apokryfos the issue with `path/to/url` is that if I have an open page like `localhost/projects/ecommerce/random_page/` then clicking that link will result to `localhost/projects/ecommerce/random_page/test/hello` I just want to keep the part of the folder of my project

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions see my comment above this one

Comment: Seems like @JustOnUnderMillions suggestion is the way to go. Just be sure you adjust the base href when you go to production.

Comment: @apokryfos see the update part of my question and you will understand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site root is always your domain name (example.com or in this case localhost) or the IP address.

It isn't clear if the end of your path is generated through `.htaccess`.

If it is, you can get the file of the script which is currently executed with `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]`.
With PHP you can now generate the path:

```
$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] && !in_array(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']), array('off','no'))) ? 'https' : 'http';
$url .= '://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$url .= (substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], 0, -strlen(basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]))));
```

This generates the path to the script which is executed, but without the filename of the file. Now you can add the path to it (e.g. `echo $url . '/path/to/url';`)

In case the path is not virtually set by `.htaccess` but are real directories, you may want to use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` and follow the path for x amount of directories to reach the path you need, then append the new path.

Another possibility is to use a constant which is either set dynamically by one of the options above or manually by typing in the path you need.

In this case the two options underneath should work:

```
define("ROOT_PATH", "/projects/ecommerce/");
```

or

```
define("ROOT_PATH", "http://localhost/projects/ecommerce/");
```

Using the magic constants from PHP could solve your problem as well:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));
```

or for PHP prior to 5.3.0:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

To output the defined constant you can just use `echo ROOT_PATH . '/path/to/url';`.